# How to build a button style based on another in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF and by following a quick tutorial I succeeded on getting a personalized button style as the following one:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#60000000" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="#FF0C0C13"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBrush" Color="#FF2E2E3E"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" Color="#FF209FD4"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#FF494968" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF2E2E3E" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" Color="AntiqueWhite"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" Color="AntiqueWhite"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" Color="AntiqueWhite"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" Color="Aqua"/>
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="Border"  BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="#FF2E2E3E">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LightBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It seems indeed that we need to override the `ControlTemplate` and that to keep some functionalities (like the behaviour while hovering the mouse) we need to define them. What is already strange to me here, is that under `ControlTemplate` it is defined a `Border` tag and then the trigger refer to that `Border`. So as a first question, why `Border` and not something else?

But now the main question is: suppose I want exactly the same button, with the same colors and functionalities but without the borders. I tried to use the BasedOn similar to the following:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyleNoBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

but no way. The only solution I found is to copy the entire code of `MyButtonStyle` and then to change only one character (!) to have `BorderThickness="0"`. But this to me looks stupid. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So as a first question, why Border and not something else?

The element named Border is the outermost element and its child will inherit most of its state, in this case the background.

> But now the main question is: suppose I want exactly the same button, with the same colors and functionalities but without the borders.

If you like a button without borders you can just set the BorderThickness property of the button to 0. directly or as a setter in the style.

> The only solution I found is to copy the entire code of MyButtonStyle and then to change only one character (!) to have BorderThickness="0". But this to me looks stupid. Can you please help?

Styles are kind of a list for what property to change on a target. The basedOn functionality will use the basedOn-style and "add" the new setter from the new style.

A Template is more like a drawing (and some graphical behavior) of the control and when you specify a new one you just throw away the old one. I would be possible to do a basedOn there. How would we determine what to use and what to replace?

Not the answer you wished for but hopefully you got it anyway.

---

```
<Border x:Name="Border"  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="#FF2E2E3E">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            </Border>
```

Will pick up the value the Button object gets on BorderThickness.

Comment: Where does this piece of code should be inserted? I tried in the button I want without border and that is using the MyButtonStyle, but it does not work

Comment: I realized that it didn't work the way I was thinking, removed that part from my answer. Is it just that you like remove the border of the button you don't retemplate it at all just add BorderThickness=0 to the button. And if you like both a new template AND be able to "turn the border on and off". You need to make sure the new border and it borderthickness in the new template get its value from the controls borderthickness and not state one on its own value. You use TemplateBinding for that.

Comment: yes I want to turn the border on and off, please show how to link the borderthickness in the new template to the control's borderthickness

Comment: I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this using MVVM (if you have not considering MVVM yet). 
In my ViewModel bound to the Button, I would add a property "IsBorderLess".

Then, on the Triggers:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBorderLess}" Value="True">
           <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBorderLess}" Value="False">
           <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   ..........
```

Comment: can you please give more details? How can I add the property IsBorderLess in xaml and where?